# How does one send Sonicwall firewall logs via gmail?

Tags: ssl, firewall, logging, gmail, sonicwall

We have a Sonicwall TZ215 that allows configuration of the logs and alerts to be sent to admin addresses.  However, we only have gmail/google accounts available to us and there is no option for enabling SSL TLS required by gmail.

Since this is firewall appliance, I would like to keep the solution within the box.  We don't have any extra machines to easily run a forwarder like stunnel.

Is there a workaround/setting to enable sonicwall logs to be sent as ssl mail via our google accounts?

Thanks, Mike

Comment: Have you thought of using a different "free" mail provider, like M$ (outlook.com),  or AOL?

Comment: Have you got this addressed?
I have tried by enabling smtp-relaying from my GoogleApps settings as suggested by Google team. Other services seems to be working with smtp-relay.gmail.com with port 25, but it didnt work for my sonicwall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume your ISP gives you a email account? if so use that one and have gmail setup to pop(3) that email account on your ISP.

Comment: So simple I'm embarrassed I didn't think of it sooner.  Thanks!